# Can Portugal "black list" my passport because I got a visa but didn't visit Portugal with it?

Tags: visas, schengen, portugal

I visited Spain last month with my family, and while applying for the visa I mentioned I would spend  max time in Portugal. I got a Schengen visa from the Portugal embassy. That was the actual plan. I did have a confirmed ticket to Portugal as well.

Then I couldn't go to  Portugal and spent the full time in Spain. After I returned, my friends planned a trip to Germany, Portugal and Austria, so I booked my ticket to Frankfurt and out from Vienna. In my itinerary I showed 3 days Germany, 4 days Portugal, and 3 days Vienna, and a confirmed booking from Frankfurt to Portugal.

When I arrived at the embassy, The consul-general went through my documents and started to question me. I was a bit nervous. He asked me about the last time, when I took a visa from here but didn't travel to Portugal. I tried to convince him. But he told me that I was "visa shopping" and told me if I apply for the visa, he will refuse it, and even black list my passport.

I did enter the embassy to submit my passport and documents. I was scared and nervous and left the embassy after a short while. Because I didn't submit my application, would the embassy still black list my passport?

Comment: More to the point, did you actually try to tell the consular officer that you had visited Portugal when you both knew that you did not?

Comment: Given that there is no border control between Spain and Portugal, how did this issue even arise? I take it you _said_ you went to Portugal and couldn't answer any question about it?

Comment: Machael , I initially  did tell him tat I did visit. As I was nervous. but at any given point I did not say I didn't visit. He did assume as I was not able to  show him any proof of my visit.to Portugal

Comment: Willeka I did not apply . As the counsellor general to me tat he would deny my visa .as I failed to show him proof of my ealier visit.

Comment: Andrew, yes I did say I did visit . And couldn't answer abt it

Comment: But the point is . After all of tat conversation with the general I did not apply for the  visa.do u think he can still black list my passport

Comment: Ali .thnx for the reply . I will apply from Germany which is my first point of entry. so I was lucky to get away. Or do u think they could have put my passport details in sis.

Comment: Usually they do it after submission or you have overstayed your visa
They simply did not accept your application and providing you the opportunity to apply other consulate

Comment: My advice is never do that again stick to your plans or at least enter the country where you got your visa

Comment: Thnx Ali. Will definitely following the  rules. And stick to the plan

Comment: The worst thing you can do is lie. You lied about having visited Portugal, and they found out. That's a big red flag.

Answer (score 2):

To me, it looks like you initially obtained a visa from Portugal and did not travel or did not stay there and then you were going to reapply again for another visa and the embassy found out that you did not visit Portugal and now they won't issue you a visa?

Consulate office told you that they would reject and blacklist your passport; I think were more generous to you.

First they could have refused your application and second they could have stored your information in SIS (Schengen Information System) that you previously mislead Portugal and breached your visa conditions which would make your future applications more vulnerable.

I'm not certain if your question is "you did not submit your application and would they still blacklist you?"

If yes, I don't think you are in trouble

For your case best for you is go for the consulate in which you entered or exit from you last Schengen visa .That would not only make you next application stronger also it would convince the visa officer that you have entered to his country and poses no threat to further applications.

My suggestion for your next visit always stick to your plans.

I obtained Schengen visa from 15 embassies and share here one experience here:

Schengen visa for Germany: I was supposed to enter from Germany and exit through Italy, I changed my route and entered through Zurich and exited through Milan so when I again reached the consulate, I faced the similar story.

However, I still stayed in Germany and I had my paid hotel receipts along-with bus and train tickets which confirmed that I stayed in Germany.

The only problem was that I was supposed to stay in Germany for 5 nights and in the end, I just stayed there 3 nights and spend most of my time in Italy so they simply refused to accept my application.

After 2 weeks I applied from Italian consulate and they issued me the visa without any difficulty.