# I changed my travel plans after entering the Schengen area. Will this cause me trouble with immigration?

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, legal, change-purpose-of-travel

I have issued a Schengen visa from the Italian embassy for tourism. In the visa application, I declared that I will enter Germany first, and then I will stay the longest in Italy.

I'm in Germany now, but I won't be able to visit Italy. My travel plans have changed and I will now be leaving the Schengen states from Germany.

Will this cause me any type of trouble?

Comment: If you leave in time, it's *extremely* unlikely you would get any problem.

Comment: @Relaxed What do you mean by "in time"? do you mean before the expiry of the visa?

Comment: Before the expiry of the visa and without exceeding the maximum duration of stay.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Schengen visa from a European country without stepping foot into it?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34318/getting-schengen-visa-from-a-european-country-without-stepping-foot-into-it)

Comment: It sounds like you may have entered Germany with the intention of traveling to Italy, after which your plans changed.  If this is true, and you can present evidence to support it if asked, then it's even more unlikely that you would have any problem.

Comment: I am voting to leave this Q open as it is about the situation of already having the visa and then changing plans, not about where to apply for it as the supposed dupe. See also that none of the answers in the supposed dupe really answer this question here!

Comment: @ A_Alrumaidh do you have a single-entry of multiple entry type visa? I am not sure if I completely agree with the advice of @Relaxed, see [this post here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/71929/32134)

Comment: @mts And I am not sure I disagree with you ;) I actually thought about mentioning potential issues with subsequent visa applications (although it still seems unlikely) but what I primarily meant is that you are extremely unlikely to run into any kind of trouble at the border on exit (it could be different on entry).

Comment: Also note that there are several things that do not add up in the question you linked to (starting with the fact that the consul general himself is unlikely to talk to applicants directly) and I suspect that the OP either misunderstood some things or withheld some details that might have prompted that response from the consulate, which I why I did not answer it back when it was asked.

Comment: @Relaxed I completely agree with your last two comments (and upvoted them) :)

Answer (score 2):

As a tourist, you probably have a visa for all Schengen states. Check your visa, it should say "Stati Schengen" or something like that. That means you can travel through **all** Schengen states as long as that travel is consistent with your statements and your itinerary in the visa application.

You wrote that you applied to visit Germany and Italy. If you simply cut your visit short and travel home partway through your itinerary, there will be no problem. If you travel to another Schengen state to catch a flight from there, there will be no problem, either. If you stay much longer in Germany than planned, there may be questions.

Comment: Just a question, how or what will prove to embassies for any future visa application that OP did not spend any time in italy, or spend x days more in Germany than promised, other than hotel bills or flight stubs etc.? There are no border controls in Schengen, so no passport stamps. X days, where it is less than total visa days. If visa was for 15 days, n OP said 6 days in Italy and 4 days in Germany, how embassies might find that he spend 8 days in Germany? Thanks

Comment: @Davinder, if the OP travels by car or train there would be no records where he was in the Schengen area. If he left the area on time, the **main** concern of the visa policy is answered, anyway.